# Is possible to use Rails ActiveModel::Validations per instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, configuration

theres an excerpt of my code:

```
module Configuracao
  extend self

  class Key
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    attr_accessor :name, :type, :default, :validations, :group, :available_values

    def initialize(params)
      params.symbolize_keys!.assert_valid_keys(:name, :type, :default, :validations, :group, :available_values)
      @group = params[:group]
      @name = params[:name]
      @type = params[:type]
      @available_values = params[:available_values]
      @default = params[:default]
      @validations = params[:validations]

      #in this way each validation is being added for all keys
      Configuracao::Key.class_eval do
        validates :value, params[:validations]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

so for every instance key i will have a diferent validation passed in a hash, example:

```
Key.new( validations: { presence: true, numericality: true } )
Key.new( validations: { length: { maximum: 30 } } )
```

There's a way to do it?

Comment: Are you having problems with your code above? In theory, this should work

Comment: yep, if i add a numericality validation on instance A, and length validation on instance B, A and B will perform the same validations, the two above

Comment: without digging to far into it, you may want to try instance_eval rather than class_eval: more: http://jimmycuadra.com/posts/metaprogramming-ruby-class-eval-and-instance-eval

Comment: same thing with Configuracao::Key.instance_eval .. and if i change to self.instance_eval i get 'undefined method'

Comment: @talski you can post your answer and accept it, this is the preferred way to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well i found a solution, maybe not so elegant or best way to do, but it works

```
def initialize(params)
  params.symbolize_keys!.assert_valid_keys(:name, :type, :default, :validations, :group, :available_values)
  @group = params[:group]
  @name = params[:name]
  @type = params[:type]
  @available_values = params[:available_values]
  @default = params[:default]
  @@current_validations = nil
  @@current_validations = @validations = params[:validations]

  class << self
    validates :value, @@current_validations unless @@current_validations.blank?
  end
end
```

now each time i instantiate a *Key*, the class will be modified only for that instance

Answer (score -1):

Will this work?

```
...
validates :all_hash_validations_pass
...

def all_hash_validations_pass
  ...iterate through the hash here, and validate each of them
end
```

If not, you should be able to use a [custom validator](http://www.perfectline.ee/blog/building-ruby-on-rails-3-custom-validators) for more control.

Comment: i could not find a solution using it, how would be a sample of each validation inside the all_hash_validations_pass method?

Comment: However it is that you create the validations hash (which is up to you, I don't know how you planned to do it), pass it into that method.

Comment: I suppose, in order for it to be in scope, you'll need to make the hash global somehow, or at least visible at the class level.